# How to update my new code so that I can unarchive data from my old app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, nskeyedunarchiver

I have an app in the App Store that is quite old.  I am trying to write an updated version.  My original app archived and unarchived data as below.  I cannot work out how to now access this data in my updated app.

```
- (void)saveGG
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:givens forKey:@"Present"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

- (void)loadGG
{
    NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        gifts = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Present"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    }
    else
    {
        gifts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }
```

Comment: In such case I would keep this code as it is. Bridge it to Swift. In new version I would check if this file exists and start migration if it does. Once migration is done then delete this file and this code will never be executed again. Goal mostly being that this code will no longer be supported but only used for migration once per user.

Comment: Thanks Matic.  My problem is that I cannot work out how to bridge this code to Swift.  I also have extra fields that didn't exist in the original app, so I'm not transferring completely like-for-like fields.

Comment: As for bridging to Swift you need a bridge header and then in it import header file of this class that should expose the two methods. With that you should be able to call methods in Swift directly and use this data. Once you load data you should then manually input data in your new classes and save them with your new fields as well.